# Display text with a string in Textblock xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a textblock, and I want to display a text with a defined string. How to do it?

The textblock:

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="45,0,0,0" Height="30" Width="386" Text="My Program ver. Version"/>
```

My string:

```
Public Version As String = "1.0a"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Version, StringFormat=My Program ver. {0}}" />
```

In your code- behind you must change `Version` to property (this property should be `ReadOnly` because it isn't change in runtime) and assign `DataContext` in constructor:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property Version As String
        Get
            Return "1.0a"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your TextBlock to update the version number every time you have a new version,
you can do it like this in C#. You can probably find out easily how to write this in VB.

This will update your TextBlock everytime you publish a new version of your program.

In XAML you bind a TextBlock text to "Version":

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Version, Mode=OneWay}" />`
```

And then in code-behind or in your view-model you can use a property for that Binding that you have in the XAML TextBlock:

```
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
          return String.Format("VERSION: {0}",DeploymentInfo.Version.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then you need to add a reference to ***"System.Deployment"*** in your project.

This will only work when you have done a "PUBLISH" of your project. When you start the debugger you will probably only see version number: 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In XAML file:

First you should name your TextBlock i have gave `tbWithNoName` for example.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbWithNoName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="45,0,0,0" Height="30" Width="386" Text="My Program ver. Version"/>
```

Then add Loaded call on Window object.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Insert Window_Loaded function to your vb file.

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    tbWithNoName.Text = tbWithNoName.Text + " " + Version
End Sub
```

This will change TextBlock's Text when Window loaded